# How do I compute numpy mean minimum maximum of multiple arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 12 one-dimensional numpy arrays of the same index (365) and I want to compute minimum, maximum and average.

So, in the end, I want to have arrays of minimum, maximum and average with index=365.

The problem is that with `numpy.mean()` or `numpy.minimum()` I cannot use more than 2 arrays...
Could anybody give an idea what I should do?

### Edit

What I have is the following:

```
A1=array([x1,x2,x3,...,x365]
A2=array([y1,y2,y3,...,y365] 
...
A12=array([z1,z2,z3,...,z365]
```

I want to compute the `min`, `max`, and average array, so I will have:

```
A_minimum=array([m1,m2,m3,...,m365],
```

where `m1=min(x1,y1,...,z1)`, `m2=min(x2,y2,...,z2)`, etc...

I hope it is clearer now! Thank you for your responses.

Comment: can you give a reproducible example and your expect output?

Comment: I assume with index you mean size. If you have 12 arrays, your final index will be of size 12

Comment: You are probably right.

Answer (score 2):

```
stacked_arrays = numpy.hstack((A1, A2, A3, ..., A12))

numpy.mean(stacked_arrays, axis=1)
```

Comment: now that you know how to do mean... it should be a simple matter to compute min and max. Look for the 'axis' flag in the documentation.

docs: 

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html#numpy.amax

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.amin.html#numpy.amin

Comment: No, this is not what I need. If you saw my recent comment, I have A1=array([x1,x2,x3,...,x365])
A2=array([y1,y2,y3,...,y365])
...
A12=array([z1,z2,z3,...,z365]) and I need to compute the array AVERAGE=array([m1,m2,m3,...,m365]), in which each of the 365 components is the mean value of the components of the initial 12 arrays: m1=(x1+y1+...+z1)/365   m2=(x2+y2+...+z2)/365   m3=(x3+y3+...+z3)/365   ...   m365=(x365+y365+...+z365)/365)

Comment: @NickEvangeliou why are you dividing by 365 when you have 12 values going into the mean?

Comment: Obviously, I have to divide by 12! Thanks for pointing this out. I was confused!!!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to calculate the mean, min and max of all the data in 12 arrays?

How about you use the numpy concatenate operator (np.r_) to stick them all together and then perform the mean/min/max operation:

```
all = np.r_[a1,a2,a3,a4 .... ,a12]
print all.mean()
print all.max()
print all.min()
```

Comment: or are you trying to calculate the min/max/mean of each of the 12 individual arrays? It is not clear in your question....